# Salesforce version of vlookup - returning counties based on zip code

Tags: formula, excel

What I want to do seems fairly programatically easy.  I could do it in Excel with a vlookup in less time than it would take me to complete this post.

I want users to be able to enter the zip code in the standard zip code field and Salesforce returns to a second text or picklist field the name of the county that corresponds to that zip code.

In our case this would only apply to a single state (MN), so just over 1000 unique zip codes that are all 1:1 relationship to county.  (While a county has many zip codes, each zip code has one and only one county.)

Is there a straightforward way to do some kind of vlookup to populate one field based on info entered in another?

Comment: "While a county has many zip codes, each zip code has one and only one county." While generally true, this statement is universal. Some zip codes straddle different counties and states. See, for instance, here for 
 states (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53918/determining-which-us-zipcodes-map-to-more-than-one-state-or-more-than-one-city). A fortiori, the same is true to counties.

Comment: For my state of Minnesota, I actually looked into it, and in MN zipcode boundaries always fall within county lines.

Answer (score 2):

I see you have this tagged as formula, I would not advice attempting a formula. There are limits to how big a formula can be and if you have over 1000 matches, you'll most likely hit this limit.

You could use a custom setting to map the zips to counties and then a trigger to automatically set the field.

We've done some developments that replace dependent pick-lists with a custom object and parent/child relationships with look-up filters for less restrictions and more customization over the pick-lists as well.

If you use the service console you can look into macros.

Overall the question is: **What do you want your end user experience to look like?**

The trigger solution is probably the best end user experience.

**Update:** Removed dependent pick list as recommendation since the limits are too low for 1000 zip codes. **Honestly the trigger option is probably your best bet.**

### Update 2

- [Custom settings with apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm)
- [Enable list custom settings](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000269861&language=en_US&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=1)
- [Configuring list custom settings](https://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/01/07/using-list-custom-settings-in-salesforce-com/)
- [Trailhead apex triggers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_intro)

Sample Code (Put in a before trigger):

```
Map<String, Zip_Code__c> zips = Zip_Code__c.getAll();

for (Account a : Trigger.New) {
    a.County__c = zips.get(a.BillingPostalCode).County__c;
}
```

Comment: It could be done pure declarative with Process Builder + Flow if desired as well.

Comment: It sure can @DavidReed I shy away from flows as they have proven time and time again to be a cause of query and cpu issues in our org as the developers of flows are less familiar with the optimization of these. With apex you get much more control. That being said you could absolutely do an apex helper class and call it from a pb for a hybrid solution as well.

Comment: You're totally right; it can be a good route in a low-code or no-code org, though.

Comment: I'm not opposed to code.  I haven't done anything in APEX yet, but I once taught myself Javascript, so I could figure it out if I know how to go about it.  It seems like there should just be a way for Salesforce to query an array with all the zip codes and counties somewhere in the org and a formula or APEX or something that matches the zip code and returns the county like a vlookup.  As far as user experience-- they type the zipcode and save the record and SFDC does the rest.  I don't think a custom object is neccessary, just looking for text or picklist result.

Comment: Updated to include documentation that you will need to do a trigger as well as a quick sample of what the code will look like.